# Set consistency level when indexing in ElasticSearch NEST client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In the ElasticSearch documentation it specifies that you can set the consistency level when indexing.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/bulk.html

However in the lastest version of the NEST client this has been removed (breaking change).

Is there a new way of doing this as it would seem that the documentation does not include anything regarding creating indexes or indexing data. The docs only contain query and aggregation text (unless I am mistaken).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html

I would like to index data into an index that has the consistency level of 'all'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency is controlled by [`wait_for_active_shards`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-index_.html#index-wait-for-active-shards), which was [added in 5.0.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-notes-5.0.0.html) (search for `wait_for_active_shards`)

```
var indexResponse = client.Index(new Message { Content = "demo" }, i => i
    .WaitForActiveShards("all")
);
```

Comment: Even when I use the wait_for_active_shards i still seem to get holes in consistency. Indexing a record and then attempting to read back from a 3 node ES cluster can still return me with nothing. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: So this does work, however I also needed to set the 'Refresh' to 'true' or 'WaitFor' in order for the operation to have completed on all shards before completing. Thanks

Comment: @WillM `wait_for_active_shards` and `refresh` do different things; the former controls _writing to shards_ i.e. write consistency, while the latter controls when those changes are actually written to disk in a new segment. Generally speaking, in a production system, you should aim to minimise manual refreshes as more segments on disk to search will not perform as well as fewer segments.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-refresh.html, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/dynamic-indices.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/translog.html